# How to install or enable imagick for WordPress deployment at Google Cloud?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, web-hosting

PHP modules perform most of the tasks on the server that make your site run. Any changes to these must be made by your server administrator.

The WordPress Hosting Team maintains a list of those modules, both recommended and required, in the team handbook (opens in a new tab).

Warning The optional module, imagick, is not installed, or has been disabled.
Warning The optional module, zip, is not installed, or has been disabled.
Warning The optional module, intl, is not installed, or has been disabled.

I read the help documentation but it's all CLI and seems complicated. Is there an easy way to enable these three modules imagick, zip, & intl?